# the fastest way to save lucene-solr search result?

Tags: search, solr, lucene, full-text-search, search-engine

Currently SQL '%like%' search is used to get all the rows which contains certain keywords. we're trying to replace MySQL like search with Lucene-Solr.

We constructed indexes,

1. queried to solr with a keyword,
2. retrieved the primary keys of all corresponding records,
3. queried to mysql with PK
4. and fetched the result.

and it got slower. damn!

I suppose that bandwidth used in 1, 2, 3 is the cause (since the result is really huge, like 1 million+), but I cannot figure any better ways.

Is there any other ways to get solr search result except CSV over http? (like file dump in mysql)

Comment: point 1 and 2 are safe, if solr is tweaked in a proper way. but i still don't understand your question. solr's default response is an XML file. you should replace mysql with solr totally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did the same procedure to combine solr and mysql which was 100-1000x faster than single mySql fulltext search .

So your workflow/procedure is not a problem in general.
The question is: where is your bottleneck.
To investigate that, you should take a look to the catalina out to see the query time of each solr request. Same on MySQL - take a look to query-time/long running queries.

We had an performance problem because the returned number of PK was very large -> so the mySQL query was very large because of an very long `where in ()` clause.

Followed by an very large MySQL statement there where lots of rows returned 200-1.000.000+

But the point is, that the application/user does not need such a big date at onces.
So we decided to work with pagination and offset (on solr side). Solr now returns only 30-50 results (depending of the pagination setting of the users application environment).

This works very fast.

//Edit: Is there any other ways to get solr search result except CSV over http?

There are different formats, like XML, PHP, CSV, Python, Ruby and JSON. To change this, you can use the `wt`parameter, like `....&wt=json`

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreQueryParameters#wt

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryResponseWriter

//Edit #2

An additional way could be not only indexing the data to solr. You could (additional) store the data to solr in order to fetch the data from solr and live without MySQL data.
it depends on your data, if that is an way for you...

Comment: I think you had a good point. But we are using this in large data mining process - so retrieving all data always happens. I suspect that extremely long mysql query is the bottleneck, too.

Comment: I'm not sure, how your environment is, but we are running solr insight tomcat. So one way to reduce traffic from Solr to your application could be by enabling gzip compression on tomcat(solr) side: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/enable-gzip-compression-in-tomcat/  But this will not reduce that big MySQL query you have to send to the MySQL server.

Comment: @Daehee Han ...please take a loot to my comment and the edit #2 of my answer

Answer (score 0):

Solr provides a way to export the results as [CSV](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CSVResponseWriter) and [JSON](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolJSON)
1 million+ is still a very large set. You can always do it in batches.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you retrieve all your MySQL database to Solr?

You can use [DIH ( Data Import Handler )](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) to retrieve all the data from MySQL and add to Solr pretty easy.

Then you will have all information you need in just one place and I think you will get a better performance.

Comment: I don't think, that data import is the focus here.

Comment: I think he search the solr with a keyword to find the pk and search the mySQL using this PK to get the data. Im saying that if the data was all in Solr it can be a lot more efficient